# Restricting the size of widgets programmatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to create the layout shown in the picture below. This shows up fine:

```
Column( Row, ListView()))
```

While this renders errors:

```
Column( Row, Row( ListView(), Column ))
```

As soon as I replace the inner `ListView()` with `Row( ListView(), Column )`, nothing shows up and I get varying error messages, based on various changes I did.

Most often, I see a `'viewport has unlimited horizontal size'`.

I guess `Listview` to be the source of the problem. That said, I'm no aware how to fix it.

Furthermore, I did find various hints on SO, but none fixed the problem.

**How do I fix the problem?**

**Update 1**

While the right `Column()` may be fixed width, the `ListView()` should take all remaining space of the screen [= availableWidth - WidhtOf(Column())].

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the ListView inside a Container And give it height/width

code

```
Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Text(
                      "1 C/G")
                ],
              )),
          Column(
            children: [],
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Indeed, this solution renders. Unfortunately, I want the inner ListView to take all available space. The right column (a property inspector) may be fixed width, while the ListView should 'grab' all the remaining width. Any hints?

Comment: so if you know the size of the right column you can 
set the Column width with container and set the width 

" MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2"

and  for the listview you can set the container width as 
 "MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8"

this  should take all the place on the screen 

NOTE: if you have a ui like first row have a width , this method above will not work 
but it should work if you set every thing with MediaQuery
i Recommend you to take a look at (MediaQuery) its responsive ui

Comment: Thank you! I'll do. Currently I'm a Flutter newbie ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Both `Row` and `Column` have a `mainAxisSize`parameter where you can set it to `MainAxisSize.min` so they will take their children's size.
Now, about the `ListView`, there is a `shrinkWrap` parameter that makes it so its max size will be its children's size. Another idea might be using a `Flexible` widget around the `ListView`, it does almost the same as `Expanded`, but the difference is: `Expanded` forces the child to occupy the remaining space, while `Flexible` allows the children to have any given size smaller than that, and that's because of its `fit` parameter that by default is `FlexFit.loose`.